# using AppCompat-21 on Lollipop device crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, build.gradle

Recently I upgraded my nexus 5 to Lollipop. and I create an app using AppCompat-21. The styles under  values-v21 are as follo

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

but when I run the app, it crashes with the information:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "geone.businspector"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

It runs great under the device pre-Lollipop...

I googled a lot and had no good solution. anybody met this before? ps: I'm using Android Studio 0.8.14 and I'm new to Android Studio. thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error clearly states that you're using the wrong theme. The activities you're using are from the `android.support` package, these activities need a `ThemeCompat` theme, not the `Theme.Material.Light`, which is for activities in `android.app` package. Rewrite your theme like so:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    </style>
</resources>
```

And this error will be gone.

Comment: thanks for answering. but this style is in value-v21 and it's auto generated by Android Studio...

Comment: @JerryGu you need to remove styles in value-21 because they can be used by `android.app.Activity` and its descendants only.

Comment: google's suggestion is here.Define Alternative Styles:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html. my device is lollipop and I think it should use value-v2l. am I wrong?

Comment: @JerryGu you can either use native android activities defined in the `android.app` package, and in this case you can override styles in `value-21` folder, OR you can stick with the activities defined in the `android.support` package. in the latter case you can't override styles in `values-21` folder, because support activities work ONLY with the `Theme.AppCompat` theme; `Theme.Holo`, `Theme.Material` and such are for the activities in `android.app`.

Answer (score 1):

Under your **values/styles.xml** you would be using **Theme.AppCompat.Light**
Use the SAME parent theme for your **values-v21/styles.xml** as well. This will get rid of the error as it did for me.

On Lollipop devices the theme works like it actually should so no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue and I got soooo tired of Googling it and seeing persons say not to use the Material Theme. Not using Material Theme changes the actionbar to gray even when you set a color for it in styles.

Anyway, the fix is that the android templates created by android studio use import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; instead of import android.app.Activity; and extend ActionBarActivity instead of activity for the main class. Just change the main class to extend an Activity instead of an ActionBarActivity. Of course more changes will have to be made if you are not using a Blank activity.